# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for annotated classess alone

Tags: spring

Am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

for the Classes for which I have used annotation (@Service)

I have mentioned the package scan correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a blunder mistake in deed. But just posting the answer because, many might do the same.

I was using Eclipse to prepare the JAR file. Eclipse did not pack the class files properly, so spring could not load the beans